# ACUMATICA: I want to invoke a simple API when a field is updated

Tags: c#, .net, acumatica

I am trying to invoke a simple web request (restful API) when a specific field is updated in Acumatica (when one field in Contact entity is updated on the screen), I know where exactly to put the code, I guess here:

```
protected void Contact_RowUpdated(PXCache cache, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{

  var row = (Contact)e.Row;

}
```

How do I invoke this web request, and how can I access the value of a certain custom field from the contact entity?

I tried the following code:

```
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("....");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var res = await client.PostAsync(
    "", new System.Net.Http.StringContent("...", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

But I've got an error that HttpClient doesn't exist in System.Net.Http namespace.

Comment: Can you please add the Stack Trace to the question? This issue doesn't seem to be related to Acumatica itself. Also, there are a lot of examples and questions with answers on how to access the values of the fields in the event handlers.

Comment: Also, are you looking for one field being updated on the screen, or the field being saved to the database? The event RowUpdated fires when any field in the row is updated on the screen. The Contact_FieldName_FieldUpdated style event fires when the field is updated on the screen. The Contact_RowPersisted is called after the entry is saved to the database. The event workflow is reviewed in detail in the Acumatica T200 course training guide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used System.Net.WebClient instead at the end.

Answer (score 0):

using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler())